# Deleting main drupal site while keeping a subdomain on drupal

Tags: wordpress, drupal, migration

I have a client who I made a wordpress site for. Initially they said I will just be able to completely delete their current drupal site and replace it with the new wordpress site.

Well, I went into their FTP today and noticed it appeared that they had a subdomain hosted using the same drupal configuration and server. This subdomain cannot be deleted or changed to wordpress (at least for now) because it's a huge Database, and a completely different site.

So here's what the FTP shows me:

[image]

Is there any way to keep the subdomains exactly how they are (installed on Drupal) while replacing the main website with a wordpress install?

I think I explained my problem to the best of my abilities, but if you have any questions, I'll be happy to clarify..

Answer (score 0):

If I were tackling this, I would do the following:

1. Make sure everything is backed up!!!!
2. within the main website folder, remove everything except for the .htaccess and the sites folder
3. Test a few sub-domains, rollback if not working
4. manually install WordPress
5. test WordPress and sub-domains